# Normalization with z-score to control for categorical variable

Tags: r, categorical-data, normalization, z-score

#Question
###With a school's semester report data I want to subset students that improved from one trimester to another while controlling for what class they are in.

Below is an example report.

```
|Student   |Teacher | S1.Grade| S2.Grade| Improvement|
|:---------|:-------|--------:|--------:|-----------:|
|Amy       |Blue    |     57.5|     75.0|        17.5|
|Becca     |Blue    |     17.5|     32.5|        15.0|
|Carol     |Blue    |     27.5|     47.5|        20.0|
|Denise    |Blue    |     40.0|     52.5|        12.5|
|Emily     |Green   |     40.0|     52.5|        12.5|
|Fiona     |Green   |     42.5|     27.5|       -15.0|
|Gabrielle |Green   |     65.0|     60.0|        -5.0|
|Hailey    |Green   |     70.0|     52.5|       -17.5|
```

The problem with my data is shown by asking of the above data:
who improved more: Denise or Emily?

There are obviously a lot of variables that affect one's grades and improvement, accordingly.

My issue with simply proceeding with the raw improvement metric is that the "improved" subset is comprised heavily of students in classes in which everyone improved. So my "improved students" subset becomes a "Ms. Blue" subset.

I would like to control for the variation in teacher's grading by finding the z-score of improvement for each class using the mean and SD for each class.

I'm an amateur with a sneaking suspicion that a z-score is misguided, still, there is enough variation in improvement distribution amongst classes that I don't feel confident accepting the raw improvement as my metric.

My plan with the z-score metric is to split it into quartiles and consider differences amongst the segments.

#How I did this in R.

```
library(dplyr)

report.ex <- structure(list(Student = structure(1:8, .Label = c("Amy", "Becca", 
    "Carol", "Denise", "Emily", "Fiona", "Gabrielle", "Hailey"), class = "factor"), 
        Teacher = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Blue", 
        "Green"), class = "factor"), S1.Grade = c(57.5, 17.5, 27.5, 
        40, 40, 42.5, 65, 70), S2.Grade = c(75, 32.5, 47.5, 52.5, 
        52.5, 27.5, 60, 52.5), Improvement = c(17.5, 15, 20, 12.5, 
        12.5, -15, -5, -17.5)), .Names = c("Student", "Teacher", 
    "S1.Grade", "S2.Grade", "Improvement"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L))

by_teacher <- report.ex %>%
        group_by(Teacher) %>%
        summarize(Improve.m = mean(Improvement), Improve.sd = sd(Improvement))

norm.ex.by_teacher <- left_join(report.ex, by_teacher, by = "Teacher") %>%
        #normalize the t12.growth by mean & sd of teacher t12.growth
        mutate(Improve.zgrowth = (Improvement - Improve.m)/Improve.sd) %>%
        mutate_each(funs(round(.,3)), -Student, -Teacher) %>%
        select(Student, Teacher, Improvement:Improve.zgrowth)
```

#Result

```
|Student   |Teacher | Improvement| Improve.m| Improve.sd| Improve.zgrowth|
|:---------|:-------|-----------:|---------:|----------:|---------------:|
|Amy       |Blue    |        17.5|     16.25|      3.227|           0.387|
|Becca     |Blue    |        15.0|     16.25|      3.227|          -0.387|
|Carol     |Blue    |        20.0|     16.25|      3.227|           1.162|
|Denise    |Blue    |        12.5|     16.25|      3.227|          -1.162|
|Emily     |Green   |        12.5|     -6.25|     13.617|           1.377|
|Fiona     |Green   |       -15.0|     -6.25|     13.617|          -0.643|
|Gabrielle |Green   |        -5.0|     -6.25|     13.617|           0.092|
|Hailey    |Green   |       -17.5|     -6.25|     13.617|          -0.826|
```

Comment: Welcome to CV! To summarize what you are saying: you want to select students based on their improvements in grade, controlling for the class that they are in. I.e. you want to select student that are better than their class mates. Is that correct?

Comment: @Pieter that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to remove the mean effect of `Teacher`. I think that normalizing by the standard deviation per class (hence the z-score) is not necessarily and makes your data less intuitive. Subtracting the mean per `Teacher` can be done easily with `dplyr`.

```
normalized_report <- report.ex %>%
  group_by(Teacher) %>%
  mutate(centralized_improvement = Improvement - mean(Improvement)) %>%
ungroup()
```

This solution is a simple but effective approach if you are interested in comparing class mates with each other.

Also dividing by the standard deviation (hence, the z-score) is not necessarily, I think. This would mean that the difference in standard deviation is also caused by the `Teacher`. E.g. if you hypothesize that a teacher gives only attention to his favorites.

Comment: Thanks for the help Pieter!

The standard deviation does vary greatly from teacher to teacher, though. While I have no evidence as to teachers playing favorites, the variation itself is reason to control for it, no?